# Facebook unique identifier

Tags: mysql, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I am using login with facebook in codeigniter.
And i used email-id as an unique identifier for my website but some of the FB account have used phone number instead of email-id while sign up. In that case we are not getting email id in FB response.

So what should be use as an unique identifier, is facebook has something which we can use for that?

I tried to use FB id, but i notices that it is not consistent for the same account. Is there any time limit for changing the FB id?

**Update**

I used this to fetch data from FB

```
$response = $this->facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,link,location,hometown,email,gender,birthday,education,friends,likes');
$ip = $this->ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$response['logout_url'] = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => base_url(). 'index.php'));
if($response!=""){
    $email = $response['email'];
    $uid = $response['id'];
    $fbId=$response['socialId'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook id is always unique in my case. I used it for identifying all users (unique key).Now for helping you. I am posting the basic codes I used for facebook authentication below.

```
 function fbcallback()
{
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'your app id',
    'app_secret' => 'your app secret',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();  

    try {  

        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();  

    }catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {  
      // When Graph returns an error  
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();  
      exit;  
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {  
      // When validation fails or other local issues  
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();  
      exit;  
    }  


    try {
      // Get the Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
      // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
      $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,birthday,location', $accessToken);
     // print_r($response);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'ERROR: Graph ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'ERROR: validation fails ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    // User Information Retrieval begins................................................
    $me = $response->getGraphUser();

    // print_r($me);

    $location = $me->getProperty('location');
    echo "Full Name: ".$me->getProperty('name')."<br>";
    echo "First Name: ".$me->getProperty('first_name')."<br>";
    echo "Last Name: ".$me->getProperty('last_name')."<br>";
    echo "Email: ".$me->getProperty('email')."<br>";
    echo "location: ".$location['name']."<br>";
    echo "Birthday: ".$me->getProperty('birthday')->format('d/m/Y')."<br>";
    echo "Facebook ID: <a href='https://www.facebook.com/".$me->getProperty('id')."' target='_blank'>".$me->getProperty('id')."</a>"."<br>";
    $profileid = $me->getProperty('id');
    echo "</br><img src='//graph.facebook.com/$profileid/picture?type=large'> ";
    echo "</br></br>Access Token : </br>".$accessToken;    

}
```

*Please try above codes and comment if that did not resolve your problem. Note the access token always change each time user login and don't use it as an identifier. After you grab these data store it in sessions, database, cookie etc according to your need and redirect to home page.*

Comment: As you suggested for using FB ID as an identifier I tried using that but in my case the IDs were different for a single user may be it gets expired  after some time period.

Comment: @PoojaSingh I think you are storing access token instead of facebook id. Facebook id is unique for all users and there is no expiring date. The access token changes each time and expires. Look at my code to see how you can obtain facebook id.

Comment: I have used facebook API to fetch the User data and No I am not storing the access token.

Comment: @PoojaSingh are you getting id by using $me->getProperty('id'); function. According to fb each user has unique fb id and it will not change. check this out https://www.quora.com/Is-the-Facebook-ID-unique-for-all-users . Please post your code for verification along with your question

Comment: updated my question, please check if I am doing it wrong?

Comment: @PoojaSingh in your case $uid = $response['id']; is your facebook id. I don't use this method. I follow the official documentation for making it. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi